# How to stop default behaviour of all the links in the entire webpage?

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink, preventdefault, dom-manipulation

I am creating project which allows users to remove elements from any webpage. The way this work in my project is that it first creates an overlay which allow user to select the elements they want to remove. Once they have selected all the elements they click on the remove button to delete those elements from webpage. Overlay has style `pointer-events: none` so that user can select the elements on the web page. Here is [jsFiddle preview of code](https://jsfiddle.net/09ad3bzj/2/).

This work perfectly fine unless a user clicks on a link which create any issues as now the user redirected to a new site. I want all the link to stop working for some time as long as there is overlay to select items for deletion.

I have tried using following code but this doesn't stop the redirection

```
 document.querySelectorAll('a').forEach(Element => {
     (Element as HTMLElement).removeEventListener('click', removeDefaultBehaviour)
   })

 const removeDefaultBehaviour= (e:MouseEvent) => {
   e.preventDefault();
 }
```

I am looking for any workaround to make it work.

Comment: Does the process need to be reversible? For example, you can overwrite the `href` attribute in order to prevent the user from being redirected, though you would need to restore it after the fact.

Comment: yes once overlay is removed i want those links to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can add

```
a {
  pointer-events: none
}
```

to your CSS file.

Comment: The OP specifies in the question that they've already tried this.

Comment: @Dakeyras no the OP did not say that, and it's indeed the solution to OP issue